# Request queue in Play framework

Tags: playframework, httprequest, akka, playframework-2.2, denial-of-service

I have recently faced a problem with request queue in Play framework. When server is overloaded and is unable to handle request on time requests are put in the queue. Even if requester disconnects request still stays in the queue and will be handled by a controller. During stress test controllers worked on requests received even 30min earlier.

This leads to kind of denial of service. Is it possible to set request queue depth or request time to live?

Any other solution will be also appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a timestamp in each request you could check?

Comment: No, we do not send a timestamp explicitly and as far as I know play does not do it also.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion thread in play dev mailing list should provide necessary insight.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/lq0H1HBiJvs

tl;dr Measuring request queue makes sense when you have a thread per request model. Incase of Play which asynchronous and non-blocking request queue doesn't really apply.